# Leaflet.js map fit bounds maxZoom not working as expected

Tags: angular, leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet.markercluster, angular-leaflet-directive

I'am using leaflet.js map in an angular project.

trying to make the map follow a marker which is getting live location data and using fitBounds() to follow the route.
but I wanna allow the user to have a range of zoom level that they can zoom in or out.
I'am passing maxZoom as 20 but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by passing the current zoom level of the map map.getZoom() which allowed the user to have control of the zoom level while following the route.